# What variable "type" is this?

Tags: php, variables, types

What is the variable type of PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ?
Is it a string?

```
<?php

    # @???? - PDO Fetch Type
    private $fetchType = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC;

?>
```

Comment: It's an integer. See the first param in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: Nothing. That's a syntax error...

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)?

It is a constant of type `INT`

> Specifies that the fetch method shall return each row as an array indexed by column name as returned in the corresponding result set. If the result set contains multiple columns with the same name, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC returns only a single value per column name.

An example:

```
<?php

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Exercise PDOStatement::fetch styles */
print("PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: ");
print("Return next row as an array indexed by column name\n");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
print("\n");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PDO::FETCH_ASSOC is INT type

you might try looking at [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)